# How to show/hide xml attributes using java DOM?

Tags: java, xml

Well, going straight to the point. i'm using java DOM to merge two xml documents in one. To do this i first created a new node to put both documents inside, making the docs, child of the created node. The father has two attributes and one of them is the same as one of my xml document.
The attribute is xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe".
I don't know if there is some xml rule but the child attribute got hide and just the father show the attribute "xmlns".

Here is a stretch of the code i got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<nfeProc versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
   -<NFe>
```

Here is what i want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
   -<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
```

And here is my code:

```
public void juntarXML () {
    File nota = new File("C:\\NotaFiscalEletronica.xml");
    File protocolo = new File("C:\\Protocolo.xml");
    //File xml = new File("C:\\xml.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    Document docNota = null;
    Document docProtocolo = null;
    Document docXML = null;

    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        docNota = docBuilder.parse(nota);
        docProtocolo = docBuilder.parse(protocolo);
        docXML = docBuilder.newDocument();

        docXML.setXmlVersion("1.0");
        // Criando nó pai que conterá os dois documentos
        Element nfeProc = docXML.createElement("nfeProc");
        nfeProc.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");
        nfeProc.setAttribute("versao", "3.10");
        docXML.appendChild(nfeProc);

        // Buscando e importando os nós dos documentos xml
        NodeList list = docXML.getElementsByTagName("nfeProc");
        Element listNode = (Element)list.item(0);
        String chave = "chave";
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            NodeList list2;
            Element list2Node;
            if (i==0) {
                list2 = docNota.getElementsByTagName("NFe"); // Nota Fiscal
                list2Node = (Element)list2.item(0);
            }else {
                list2 = docProtocolo.getElementsByTagName("protNFe"); // Protocolo
                list2Node = (Element)list2.item(0);
                chave = list2Node.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent(); // Recuperando a chave
            }

            Node importedNode = docXML.importNode(list2Node, true);
            listNode.appendChild(importedNode);
        }

        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transFactory.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(docXML);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        trans.transform(source, result);

        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\" + chave + ".xml"));
        String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
        //System.out.println(xmlOutput);
        output.write(xmlOutput);
        output.close();

    }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I had try to re-create the attribute of the node "NFe" and there is no results.
I already checked if the attribute is still there and it is. It just disappear when i put it into a xml document.

So, there is a way to show it??

Taking the opportunity, in the case of "nfeProc", can i set something to not order the attributes alphabetically, to stay the order i add them??

Since now i thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two XMLs are the same for a DOM. Descendants inherit the namespace definitions until they are redefined.

So the XML serializer should optimize the the XML and keep only the needed namespace definitions. That means ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <NFe>
  ...
```

... is the expected XML document. Here is no reason to have an identical namespace definition on a child element.

Additionally, use `createElementNS()` - the namespace aware variant of `createElement()`. This should add the xmlns-attributes automatically as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ThW. Like you said, doesn't matter to have identical namespace, i tested in the program that i wanted to import and it validate normally. When i use "createElementNS()" the "xmlns" began to show as the first attribute like i wanted. So thank you again!!